# ¿Cómo construir un árbol binario en C ++?

Tags: c++

Quiero construir un "binary tree" para probar un algoritmo cuyo repositorio [está en GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/NestedMonteCarloForBinaryTrees). 
Quiero construir el árbol siguiente :

```
                           10
                         /    \
                        6      14
                       / \    /  \
                      5   8  11  18
```

Para hacer, codifiqué dos archivos fuente dos headers y un main.

Sin embargo cuando intento compilar con `$ gcc main.c -o NestedMonteCarlo` tengo

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/NestedMonteCarlo$ gcc main.c -o NestedMonteCarlo
In file included from main.c:5:0:
Board.h:6:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘public’
     public:
     ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:5: error: ‘seed’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     seed = atoi (argv [1]);
     ^
main.c:10:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:10:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atoi’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     seed = atoi (argv [1]);
            ^
main.c:11:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘srand’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     srand (seed);
     ^
main.c:14:10: error: ‘true’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   while (true) {
          ^
main.c:15:5: error: unknown type name ‘Board’
     Board b;
     ^
main.c:16:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(5);
   ^
main.c:17:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(6);
   ^
main.c:18:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(8);
   ^
main.c:19:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(10);
   ^
main.c:20:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(11);
   ^
main.c:21:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(14);
   ^
main.c:22:3: error: request for member ‘insert’ in something not a structure or union
  b.insert(18);
   ^
```

Le estoy pidiendo indulgencia, soy bastante nuevo en C ++. Es probable que confundiera C con C ++.

Aqui estan mis archivos.

#### main.c

```
//#include "nestedSH.c"
//#include "nestedSimple.c"
//#include "nrpa.c"
//#include "beamnrpa.c"
#include "Board.h"
#include "Node.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv []) {
  if (argc > 1)  {
    seed = atoi (argv [1]);
    srand (seed);
  }

  while (true) {
    Board b;
    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(6);
    b.insert(8);
    b.insert(10);
    b.insert(11);
    b.insert(14);
    b.insert(18);
    //nestedSimple(b, 3);
    //bestBoard.print (stderr);
    //fprintf (stderr, "best score %lf\n", bestBoard.score ());
    break;
  }
}
```

#### Node.h

```
#ifndef DEF_BOARD
#define DEF_BOARD

class Node

{

    private:
        int key_value;
        node *left;
        node *right;


};

#endif
```

#### Node.c

```
#include "Node.h"
```

#### Board.h

```
#ifndef DEF_BOARD
#define DEF_BOARD

struct Board{

    public:
        btree();
        ~btree();

        void insert(int key);
        node *search(int key);
        void destroy_tree();
        void legalMoves(Move moves);

    private: // why having put the same ones
        void destroy_tree(node *leaf);
        void insert(int key, node *leaf);
        node *search(int key, node *leaf); //

        node *root;

};


#endif
```

#### Board.c

```
#include "Board.h"

int board::legalMoves(moves) //pb c'est quoi moves, un tableau de Move et du coup il faut creer la classe Move ?
{

}

board::board()
{
  root=NULL;
}

void board::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    destroy_tree(leaf->left);
    destroy_tree(leaf->right);
    delete leaf;
  }
}

void board::insert(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(key< leaf->key_value)//if the value wa want to insert is 
  {
    if(leaf->left!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->left);
    else
    {
      leaf->left=new node;
      leaf->left->key_value=key;
      leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }  
  }
  else if(key>=leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->right!=NULL)
      insert(key, leaf->right);
    else
    {
      leaf->right=new node;
      leaf->right->key_value=key;
      leaf->right->left=NULL;  //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->right=NULL; //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
}

node *board::search(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    if(key==leaf->key_value)
      return leaf;
    if(key<leaf->key_value)
      return search(key, leaf->left);
    else
      return search(key, leaf->right);
  }
  else return NULL;
}

node *board::search(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    if(key==leaf->key_value)
      return leaf;
    if(key<leaf->key_value)
      return search(key, leaf->left);
    else
      return search(key, leaf->right);
  }
  else return NULL;
}

// public insert
void board::insert(int key)
{
  if(root!=NULL)
    insert(key, root);
  else
  {
    root=new node;
    root->key_value=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
  }
}

// public destroy
void board::destroy_tree()
{
  destroy_tree(root);
}

// public search
node *board::search(int key)
{
  return search(key, root);
}
```

¡Muchas gracias de antemano por sus luces!

Comment: `gcc` es para **C**; para **C++**, se usa `g++` :`g++ main.c -o NestedMonteCarlo` :-)

Comment: La primera pista de estar usando el compilador equivocado es que el compilador no sabe lo que es `true` xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código del GitHub intente compilarlo, y esta inconsistente en la declaracion de nombres en las clases y struct.

Mire el articulo principal que esta haciendo referencia en GitHub (https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html) y ahi me parecio mas lógico.

Recompile el código que muestra en esa lección y te queda esto:

main.cpp

```
#define NULL 0
struct node
{
  int key_value;
  node *left;
  node *right;
};

class btree
{
    public:
        btree();
        ~btree();

        void insert(int key);
        node *search(int key);
        void destroy_tree();

    private:
        void destroy_tree(node *leaf);
        void insert(int key, node *leaf);
        node *search(int key, node *leaf);

        node *root;
};

btree::btree()
{
  root=NULL;
}

btree::~btree()
{
  destroy_tree();
}

void btree::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    destroy_tree(leaf->left);
    destroy_tree(leaf->right);
    delete leaf;
  }
}

void btree::insert(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(key< leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->left!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->left);
    else
    {
      leaf->left=new node;
      leaf->left->key_value=key;
      leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }  
  }
  else if(key>=leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->right!=NULL)
      insert(key, leaf->right);
    else
    {
      leaf->right=new node;
      leaf->right->key_value=key;
      leaf->right->left=NULL;  //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->right=NULL; //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
}
void btree::insert(int key)
{
  if(root!=NULL)
    insert(key, root);
  else
  {
    root=new node;
    root->key_value=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
  }
}
node *btree::search(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    if(key==leaf->key_value)
      return leaf;
    if(key<leaf->key_value)
      return search(key, leaf->left);
    else
      return search(key, leaf->right);
  }
  else return NULL;
}

node *btree::search(int key)
{
  return search(key, root);
}

void btree::destroy_tree()
{
  destroy_tree(root);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv []) {
    btree b;
    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(6);
    b.insert(8);
    b.insert(10);
    b.insert(11);
    b.insert(14);
    b.insert(18);
}
```

Para compilarlo utiliza el siguiente comando

```
g++ main.c -o foo
```

Esta utilizando clases, por lo que tenes que usar el compilador de C++

Espero que te ayude!